# Appendchild not posting form data in firefox

Tags: php, javascript, firefox, post, appendchild

I have an appendchild-function that adds form elements. In IE, everything works fine; the `process.php` is able to `$_POST` it. But in firefox, it doesnt send the data.

Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var i=0;

        function addElement()
        {
            var ni = document.getElementById('org_div1');
            var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
            var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
            numi.value = num;
            var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            var divIdName = num;  newDiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);

            newDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="work" /><input type="file"
class="fileupload" size="80" name="file' + (num) +'" onclick="addElement()"/> <a
  class="removelink" onclick=\'removeElement('+divIdName+')\'>Remove This File</
a>';

            // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
            ni.appendChild(newDiv);
        }

        function removeElement(divNum)
        {
            var d = document.getElementById('org_div1');
            var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);

            d.removeChild(olddiv);
        }

</script>
```

---

```
<td>
    <div class="file_input_wrapper">        
        <input type="hidden" value="1" id="theValue" />
        <div id='org_div1'>
            <input type="file" class="fileupload" name="file1" size="80" onclick="addElement()" />
        </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Is the element actually added in firefox? Do you get any javascript errors probably? The data of which form element you add is missing: the text or the file?

Comment: No errors. The javascript works, when i click the field a new field pops up, but when the form is submitted, the data doesnt get passed through. @hakre

Comment: *Which* data does not get passed through? You're adding two fields. Data of both?

Comment: @hakre no just the data of the ones added from the onclick (appendchild)

Comment: ***which*** of the ones. You're adding two fields.

Comment: I suspect adding via the innerHTML is causing this. You need to use DOM methods, createElement, etc. not innerHTML for the form elements as well. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem...

Basically, I had this..

```
<div>
<form>
</div>
</form>
```

And changed to this..

```
<form>
<div>
</div>
</form>
```

Seems firefox doesnt like invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's field name array functionality to get around having to keep track of your field names. Simply name the field like this:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" ... />
                              ^^--- array notation
```

and PHP will handle each file box as a separate member in the $_FILES array after the form's submitted. This frees you up from all the extra overhead of keeping track of how many boxes there are and hidden form fields to store the value.

You may want to reconsider having the file element's onclick be the thing that adds a new file input. What happens if someone clicks on the "browse" button to add a file? They'll get a new file input box, even though they may only have wanted one. If they choose the wrong file or change their minds later and click browse again to change the file selection, they'll get yet another input box.

Consider having a dedicated "add another box" button instead.

Comment: That sounds good but still, all the form elements inside appendchild do not get passed to the server in firefox. I even tested a standard textbox with name="text" and it only worked in IE

Comment: Check source if they are even added inside the form element or not.

Comment: @Marc B Yes. The original file tag that is there DOES get passed through, the only ones that dont are the ones that are added onclick

Comment: @Jonah Katz: That's not answering the question. Are the newly added fields part of the form element in source (in the browser)?

Comment: @hakre well no, javascript doesnt actually update the source code

Comment: @Jonah Katz: You must check the dynamic source-code. Inspect with a tool like Firebug for Firefox. That will help you to tackle the issue down.

Comment: @hakre Oh ok. I just checked on firebug and they are indeed there, name and syntax and all

Comment: Then submit the form and check on the NET tab which data is actually transfered with the POST request. Is the data transfered by firefox?

Comment: @hakre Never knew about that. The only one posted is the original upload field. None of the addchilds.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to ask where your form tag is located? Before or after table tag? I had similar problem and my form tag was inside table. When I put form tag outside of table everything worked fine.

Site doesn't work anymore.
Here is working example. I used your code. Only two thing I changed is 
`<input type="text" name="work[]" />` instead of `<input type="text" name="work" />`
and you was missing one `</div>` closing div tag

here is code (tested on IE7, IE8, FF and google chrome)

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['btnProsledi'])){
print_r($_POST);
echo "<br />";
print_r($_FILES);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i=0;

    function addElement()
    {
        var ni = document.getElementById('org_div1');
        var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
        var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
        numi.value = num;
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var divIdName = num;  newDiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);

        newDiv.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="work[]" /><input type="file"  class="fileupload" size="80" name="file' + (num) + '" onclick="addElement()"/> <a class="removelink" onclick=\'removeElement(' + divIdName + ')\'>Remove This File</a>';

        // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
        ni.appendChild(newDiv);
    }

    function removeElement(divNum)
    {
        var d = document.getElementById('org_div1');
        var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);

        d.removeChild(olddiv);
    }

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="proba" type="text" id="proba" value="" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
<div class="file_input_wrapper">        
    <input type="hidden" value="1" id="theValue" />
    <div id='org_div1'>
        <input type="file" class="fileupload" name="file1" size="80" onclick="addElement()" />
    </div>
    </div>
</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input name="btnProsledi" type="submit" id="btnProsledi" value="Submit" />
    </td>
</tr>
 </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is indeed outside. Youve put form fields inside an appendchild before? if so, can you send me a link to your code? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm unfortunately in Firefox the inputs from the appendChild still arent being posted. Theyre only going through in IE, some bug in Firefox perhaps..

Comment: hmm, on my FF 5.0 it is working good. I have FF 5.0 on windows XP

Comment: Same .. very strange.. youre sure its posting? You checked firebug or something?