# PHP Undefined $_POST input created via Javascript createElement and appendChild

Tags: javascript, php, undefined, appendchild, createelement

I am creating dynamic input rows to POST it into MySQL database
the first row is mandatory, so I created the FORM and Inputs via HTML for the first row
Then created a button and addEventListener function to append any additional row dynamically

**Error**
Actually, all nodes and children are working normally from the DOM side without any problem 
[image] 
[image] 
When I submit the form, only the first static row is posted but any appended rows give **Undefined array key**

**myJsFile.js**

```
document.getElementById('add_row').addEventListener('click',function(e){

 var my_tbody = document.querySelector('.my_tbodyClass');
 var my_tr = document.createElement('tr');
 my_tbody.appendChild(my_tr);

 var my_div = document.createElement('div');

 var my_td = document.createElement('td');
 var my_input = document.createElement('INPUT');
 my_input.setAttribute('type','number');
 my_input.setAttribute('name','myRows[]');

 my_tr.appendChild(my_td);
 my_div.appendChild(my_input);

 my_td.appendChild(my_div);


});
```

**myphpFile.php**

```
function execute_dynamicRow()
{
    global $dbConnection;
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['submitedDynamicRows'])) {

        $myRows = $_POST['myRows'];
        $myRowsSerialized = serialize($myRows);

        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbConnection, "INSERT INTO all_dynamic_rows(dynamic_rows) VALUES(?)");
        $stmt_bind_param = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $myRowsSerialized);
        $stmt_execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        if (!$stmt) {
            die("Query Error " . mysqli_error($dbConnection));
        }
    }
}
```

**myform.php**

```
<?php myform(); ?>
                        
<form method="post">
  <table class="table table-flush">
    <thead> 
      <tr>
        <th class="text-uppercase text-secondary">Add You Number</th>
        <th class="text-uppercase text-secondary">Add Row</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="my_tbodyClass">
      <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
              <input type="number" name="myRows[]">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-icon btn-3" id="add_row" type="button">
            <span class="btn-inner--text">Add New Row</span>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>                                
   </tbody>
  </table>
 <div class="input-group input-group-outline my-3">
  <input type="submit" name="submitedDynamicRows" class="btn btn-info" value="Add Tax Slab">
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where are you getting undefined array key? You never care about `$_POST['myRows']` individual elements, you store whatever you receive as-is.

Comment: You append `my_input` to `my_div`, but you never append `my_div` to anything in the DOM. If you expand that `<tr><td></td></tr>` you added, it should be empty. Maybe consider using a [content template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) instead? Might be easier to maintain since you don't need to create the full hierarchy using JS, and you can define it in your HTML context (getting full syntax highlighting in your IDE etc).

Comment: _"only the first static row is posted but any appended rows give Undefined array key"_ - As pointed out, that makes zero sense in the posted code. There's nothing in it that would detect if you only get the static input or not.

Comment: @M.Eriksson 
I appended my_td.appendChild(my_div); , Just it dropped from me when I paste the code here in Stackoverflow, and when I expand the <tr> in the inspect element I see the Div and the input normally without any missing hierarchy, and also I make sure that the attribute name="myRows[]" is there in the appended input

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález PHP $_POST cannot read the appended input

Comment: @M.Eriksson Here is the screenshot that confirms for me that the appended elements are added without any problems https://prnt.sc/MUaQnfnB6zsA

Comment: Did you mean to ping me? That doesn't seem to be an answer to my question. 

Comment: _"PHP $_POST cannot read the appended input"_ - You need to tell us how you determined that you can read the static `myRows` but not the appended ones. There's nothing in the posted code that differentiates between the static and the appended inputs. All you're doing is fetching `$_POST['myRows']`, which will _always_ work as long as you have the static input, no matter if any appended one exists or not.

Comment: The value of the appended inputs is not added to the database, just the static one is added, as you see I added the attribute name as array myRows[] then I serialize myRows, and when I tried to add multiple static rows, all of the serialized successfully added in the database, otherwise the appended inputs not reflecting in the database,

Comment: Another note, I tried to change the attribute name for the appended inputs into jsRows[] and changed $_POST['jsRows'] , just for testing purpose to separate the appended inputs from the static one, I got Undefined array key jsRows, that means for a reason "PHP $_POST cannot read the appended input"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698685/appendchild-not-posting-form-data-in-firefox